# question for liminf of function

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Let $v(x)=e^{-|x|^2}-e^{-1}$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $|x|\le 1$. For $x_0$ satisfying $|x_0|=1$ and $x$ with $|x|<1$, I'd like to show

> $$\liminf_{x \to x_0} \frac{v(x)}{|x-x_0|}>0,$$
>   where the angle $x_0-x$ and $x_0$ is less than $\frac{\pi}{2}-\delta$ for some $\delta\in (0,1).$

Since $v(x)>0$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $|x|< 1$, it is clear that 
$\liminf_{x \to x_0} \frac{v(x)}{|x-x_0|}\ge 0.$ It seems that it is related to directional derivative.

Note that 
(i) $v$ is radial function.

(ii) $v(x_0)=0,$ and

(iii) for unit vector $w$ which is perpendicular to $x_0$, the directional derivative $D_w(x_0)=0.$

Intuitively, with the above information, it seems to be true that $\liminf_{x \to x_0} \frac{v(x)}{|x-x_0|}>0,$ where the angle $x_0-x$ and $x_0$ is less than $\frac{\pi}{2}-\delta$ for some $\delta\in (0,1),$ but **I don'k know how to prove it with the definition of liminf rigorously**

Please let me know if you have any idea or comment about my question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to approach $x_0$ over a line you can say $x=x_0+hz$ where $z$ is a unit vector in the direction of interest and $h$ is a positive scalar. Then $$||x||^2 = ||x_0||^2 + 2hx_0^Tz + h^2||z||^2 = 1 + 2hc + h^2$$ where $c=x_0^Tz$. Then use L'Hopital's rule for $$ \lim_{h\rightarrow0} \frac{e^{-(1 + 2hc + h^2)} - e^{-1}}{h}$$

Comment: I didn't understand your description of angle (for example, what is $\vec{n}$?) but likely you can relate the $c$ constant to your desired angle, since it is the inner product of $x_0$ and $z$.

Comment: @Michael  Thanks for your answer. I think you are right for directional derivative with specific vector, but I’d like to know how to use liminf in order to show the desired result.

Comment: The above limit exists, and so is equal to the $\liminf$.

Comment: @Michael First $\vec{n}$ is $x_0/\|x_0\|$. I don’t understand your answer, The above limit exists, and so is equal to the $liminf$. Would you explain it in detail with the definition or property of liminf?

Comment: I am quite surprised that $\vec{n} = x_0/||x_0||$ as that is not clear from the question. But you state that $||x_0||=1$, so isn't $\vec{n}=x_0$? Why do you introduce $\vec{n}$? You can compute the above limit I give with $h$, it is indeed somthing that exists.  In general $\lim=\limsup=\liminf$ whenever $\lim$ exists.  If you want to change the angle as you are approaching $x_0$ then just put a bound on the $c$ constant, say, $c\leq c^*$ and then you have an inequality relationship.

Comment: @Michael Sorry for my unclear question. I should have given the information clearly. Anyway, it is related to the unit ball. My confusion is “is it possible to use directional derivative as when we consider $liminf$ as $x\to x_0$. Would you give your comment as answer. Now I cannot use computer, so that I use my cell phone to see your comment. It is hard to understand your comment clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\{x[k]\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that 
$$x[k]=x_0+h[k]z[k] \quad \forall k \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$$ 
where $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a unit vector (i.e., $||x_0||=1$), and for each $k \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$  we have that $z[k] \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a unit vector and $h[k]$ is a positive number.  Notice that 
$$h[k] = ||x[k]-x_0|| \quad \forall k \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$$ 
Suppose that 
$$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} h[k]=0$$

Since $x_0$ and $z[k]$ are unit vectors, we have $x_0^Tz[k] = \cos(\theta[k])$ where $\theta[k]$ is the angle between vectors $x_0$ and $z[k]$. 
Suppose the angle is constrained so that there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that  $x_0^Tz[k] \leq -\epsilon$ for all $k \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$. 
So 
\begin{align*}
||x[k]||^2 &= ||x_0+h[k]z[k]||^2 \\
&= ||x_0||^2 + 2h[k]x_0^Tz[k] + h[k]^2||z[k]||^2 \\
&= 1 + 2h[k](x_0^Tz[k]) + h[k]^2 \\
&\leq 1 -2\epsilon h[k] + h[k]^2
\end{align*}
Then
$$ \frac{e^{-||x[k]||^2}-e^{-1}}{||x[k]-x_0||} \geq \frac{e^{-(1-2\epsilon h[k]+h[k]^2)} - e^{-1}}{h[k]} $$
And you can take the $\lim\inf$ of both sides as $k\rightarrow\infty$ (the right-hand-side limit exists in the usual $\lim$ sense and indeed converges to a specific positive number).